# Get input value and display it in other template

Tags: python, django, web

sorry I just learned programming

I have registration template and registration success template.

after user fill the form registration, it will be redirect to registration success template

How to get input value['email'] from registration template and display it in registration success template ?

views.py

```
class RegisterFormView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'home/register.html'

def get(self, request):
    user_form = UserForm()
    return self.render_to_response({
        'base_url' : settings.BASE_URL,
        'user_form': user_form,

    })

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.full_name = user_form.cleaned_data.get("full_name")
            user.email = user_form.cleaned_data.get("email")
            user.phone_number = user_form.cleaned_data.get("phone_number")
            user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data.get("password"))
            password = user_form.cleaned_data.get("password")
            profile = Profile.objects.create(created_by=user)
            user.save()
            return redirect(reverse("home:register-success"))
        else:
            user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
    return self.render_to_response({
        'base_url' : settings.BASE_URL,
        'user_form': user_form,
    })
```

register.html

```
{{user_form|crispy}}
```

register-success.html

```
we have send email activation to {{user.email}}
```

**EDIT**

register views.py

```
class RegisterSuccessView(TemplateView):

template_name = 'home/register-success.html'

def get(self, request):
    return self.render_to_response({
        'base_url' : settings.BASE_URL,
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try replace

```
return redirect(reverse("home:register-success"))
```

to

```
return render(self.request, template_name='home/register-success.html', context={'user': user})
```

If you want to have another URL for register-success.html you can create an additional view with page and context return

Comment: Please see in my edit question, I have add a registersuccess views.py

Comment: Please see in my edit question, I have add a registersuccess views. where I can add return context in register success views ?